# Function not called in render part of Route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, react-router

I'm creating a private route for checking if a user is authenticated before letting them access a specific page. The problem is that the checkCredentials() function is not called. I'm still really new to React(and Javascript) so I would like to know why this happens.

Also, the Route render takes in a function according to the [doc](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/render-func) but instead of being wrapped in braces they are in parentheses. Is this a React thing?

```
 render={(props) => (
            checkCredentials() ? <Component {...props}/> : (<Redirect to='/login'></Redirect>)
          )}
```

Code is below:

```
 async function checkCredentials() {
      // try {
      //   const result = axios.post('http://localhost:5000/api/auth/check', {withCredentials:  true});
      //   if (result.data.status === 200) {
      //     return true;
      //   } else {
      //     return false;
      //   }
      // } catch(error) {
      //   return false;
      // }
      return false;
    }
    function PrivateRoute({component: Component, ...rest}) {
      return(
          <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
            checkCredentials() ? <Component {...props}/> : (<Redirect to='/login'></Redirect>)
          )}></Route>
      ); 
    }
```

**UPDATE:**
This is now what the private route looks like:

```
function PrivateRoute({component: Component, ...rest}) {
  
  const [auth, setAuth] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    checkCredentials();
  },[]);

  async function checkCredentials() {
    try {
      const result = await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/api/auth/check', {withCredentials:  true});
      if (result.data.status === 200) {
        setAuth(true);
      } else {
        setAuth(false);
      }
    } catch(error) {
      setAuth(false);
    }
  }

  return(
      <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
        auth ? <Component {...props}/> : (<Redirect to='/login'></Redirect>)
      )}></Route>
  ); 
}
```

The checkCredentials func is now being called. The problem is now that the user is being redirected to login even before the auth check sends a response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to perform an asynchronous call on `render` function in `React` which doesn't work.

1. Use a state to check for redirection.
2. Do the `auth check` on mounting of the component.
3. Update the state and render your component accordingly.

Best case would be to get the `token` from the server and store it in the `localStorage` (browser) and check for permission by decoding the `token`

Something like this would suffice :-

```
 const [redirect, setRedirect] = React.useState(null);
 async function checkCredentials() {
      try {
        const result = axios.post('http://localhost:5000/api/auth/check', {withCredentials:  true});
        if (result.data.status === 200) {
          setRedirect(true)
          
        } else {
          setRedirect(false)
        }
      } catch(error) {
          setRedirect(false)
      }
    }
    if (redirect === null) return null;
      return(
          <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
            redirect ? <Component {...props}/> : (<Redirect to='/login'></Redirect>)
          )}></Route>
      );
```

Comment: I did something similar to your code and the redirect now works, although not correctly. What's happening is that it redirects me back to the login page immediately before the axios request gives back the response (async call). Also, I am using httpOnly cookies to store the JWT because I've heard storing it in localStorage is not as secure. I would like to implement this using cookies first to see if its doable before using localStorage.

Comment: You can assign the initial state to null. Render nothing when it is null. 
Only render after the API is complete.
I have updated the code though.

Comment: The code works now. Thank you. I'd like to ask though if this(sending JWT in cookie) is an unusual approach to checking if user is authenticated upon visiting a certain path. I haven't seen some examples doing the same on the web.

Comment: No. Not at all. Seems fair.